# How to make two checkboxes sit next to each other in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, jcheckbox

I have two JCheckBox's and one JEditorPane. I am looking for an output as under

[image]

But my current code is somewhat messy for which I am not able to

```
private void createContents()
  {    
    JEditorPane  license;
    JCheckBox confirmBox;
    JCheckBox declineBox;   

    license = new JEditorPane("text/html", "");
    license.setText (buildEulaText());
    license.setEditable(false);   
    confirmBox = new JCheckBox("I accept.", false); 
    declineBox = new JCheckBox("I decline.", false); 
    add(license, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(confirmBox, BorderLayout.SOUTH); 
    add(declineBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);   //I know this is wrong 
  }
```

Comment: Note: These should be radio buttons, not checkboxes. Or a single checkbox will do (Checking is "I accept", not checking is "I decline"). Using two checkboxes means that you allow the user to both accept and decline at the same time.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, I accepted my mistake and corrected it. It is radiobutton. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to compose the layouts using a new `JPanel` with a [`FlowLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html).

```
add(license, BorderLayout.CENTER);
JPanel boxes = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
// FlowLayout is the JPanel default layout manager, so
// boxes = new JPanel(); works too :)
boxes.add(confirmBox);
boxes.add(declineBox);
add(boxes, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

But you can also take a look at the [`GridBagLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).

Answer (score 1):

Create a new JPanel to hold all the checkboxes, then add this to your panel/frame.

```
JPanel checkBoxesPane = new Panel();

checkBoxesPane.add( confirmBox );
checkBoxesPane.add( declineBox );

add( checkBoxes, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would highly recommend to do it in javafx rather than in Java swing. It is the later Technology and much better according to my opinion.

If you still want to do it in Java swing, here is the code:

```
JPanel panel = new Panel();
panel.add(confirmBox);
panel.add(declineBox);
add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

I didn't test the code, but it should work with this code.